# No option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8

Tags: 12.04

While trying to install Ubuntu, the installer does not give me the option of installing alongside Windows 8.  It instead gives me the option to install inside Windows 8.  What should I do?

Comment: ignore Help installing a patch inside wine .... answer the other

Answer (score 1):

When you see a prompt to install inside Windows 8, that suggests that you opened the installer from within Windows while it was booted.

You cannot install Ubuntu alongside Windows when you are booted into the Windows system.  You need to write the installation ISO to a USB or a DVD, and then boot to the USB or DVD.

Please also refer to [this question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) if you run into problems, as Windows 8 systems that use UEFI won't work with Ubuntu side-by-side and you may have to make changes to make it work and behave.

Comment: I already did write the installation iso to a usb and then booted.

Comment: @bilal obviously not, if it says install inside Windows.  You need to change your BIOS or UEFI settings to boot from USB first.  Otherwise the system wouldn't have suggested installing inside Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a bug. I'm not sure if it's a known bug, but I can confirm its existence. Unlike you, I'm running Windows 7. After booting an Ubuntu 14.04 - Desktop X86-32 Disc I was not greeted with the expected "install alongside Windows" option, but instead "install inside Windows" if you click "install inside Windows" it reboots your computer. I would like to emphasize this is not a Wubi installation attempt. The disc was booted. I am an experienced user who has installed Ubuntu and Windows many times, so I know how to boot an Ubuntu dvd/usb.

Since the installer did recognize the Windows installation I just needed to manually put the installation settings in using "something else", and was able to successfully triple boot Ubuntu, Windows 7, and Windows XP. In your case keep in mind that Ubuntu doesn't play nice with Windows 8 so you will likely need to run `boot-repair` after installing Ubuntu.